# Como sumo coincidencias de 2 arreglos en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, match

he hecho una forma para sumar las coincidencias que hay en el array 2 respecto del array 1

```js
array1 = [2, 4, 6];
array2 = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2];

let c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  if (array1[0] === array2[i]){
      c1 += 1;
  }
  if (array1[1] === array2[i]){
      c2 += 1;
  }
  if (array1[2] === array2[i]){
      c3 += 1;
  }
}
console.log(c1, c2, c3) // 3 2 2
```

Funciona, pero mi duda es si hay una forma más práctica, ya que no se como lo haría si fueran mas elementos, no sería bueno tener `c50, c70`, o hacer `if (array1[50])`, etc. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría usando 'map' y 'find'. De esta manera se puede obtener el mismo resultado que el tuyo y funciona independientemente del tamaño de el array.

```js
array1 = [2, 4, 6];
array2 = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2];

const countArray = array1.map(
  (array1Item) => array2.filter(
    (array2Item) => array2Item === array1Item,
  )?.length || 0,
);

console.log(countArray);
```

Si quieres que el resultado sea un objeto, hay que utilizar un `reduce`, de esta manera:

```js
const countObject = array1.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  [cur]: acc[cur] || 0 + array2.filter((array2Item) => array2Item === cur)?.length || 0
}), {});

console.log(countObject);
```

Comment: Me ha encantado tu respuesta, funciona y logro entenderla. Sabes como podria hacer un objeto? es decir, q sea por ej: [ {'2': 3}, {'4': 2}, {'6': 2}, es decir, insertarle un key y luego su valor que seria el cont de cada numero, estoy intentando y no me resulta, aun asi muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado. He editado mi respuesta para que el resultado sea un objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo con distintos métodos para recorrer arreglos, también puedes utilizar un objeto para guardar todos los elementos que tengas en el primer arreglo, primero con un forEach llenamos el objeto, y en el segundo forEach, recorremos el segundo arreglo para contar cuántas veces se repite el elemento dentro de nuestro objeto, de esta forma sólo tenemos que recorrer los arreglos 2 veces y te ahorras tiempo de ejecución

```js
const array1 = [2, 4, 6];
const array2 = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2];
let objectMap = {}

array1.forEach(element => {
    objectMap[element] = 0;
})

array2.forEach(element => {
    if(objectMap[element] != undefined){
    objectMap[element] += 1
  }
})

console.log(objectMap)
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el codigo, pero funciona. Mi pregunta es, como saco del objeto los elementos que necesito? porque si fuera un arreglo los extraigo en orden con un map, pero no puedo usar esa funcion "objectMap.map is not a function", gracias por tu tiempo Jorge

Comment: Puedes obtener las llaves haciendo Object.keys(objectMap), de esa forma te guarda las llaves en un arreglo, y ya sólo tu las mandarías llamar usando objectMap[key] recorriendo este arreglo que te regresa Object.keys